# 9 counters and the total of three of them

Tags: probability

> There are $9$ counters in a bag, three marked with $2$ and six marked with $5$. Lev takes at random $3$ counters and adds their numbers. What is the probability this sum is odd?

My turn :
As Lev takes 3 balls from the bag it is equivalent to taking the balls one after another one without replacement 
The probability that the total is odd is equivalent to the probability of at least one the three balls odd which is $1- P$(the three balls are even)
$$= 1- \frac{3}{9}\times \frac{2}{8}\times \frac{1}{7}$$
$$= \frac{83}{84}$$
Is the answer correct ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct. The sum is odd iff *one or three* of the drawn counters is odd, which has probability (via the hypergeometric distribution)
$$\frac{\binom32\binom61+\binom30\binom63}{\binom93}=\frac{18+20}{84}=\frac{19}{42}$$

Comment: You are right but i think the answer you have found is the probability that the sum is even so the the probability of the sum is odd = $1-\frac{19}{42}= \frac{23}{42}$

Comment: @HussienMohamed No. Check again.

Comment: @HussienMohamed $2+2+2=6$, $2+2+5=9$, etc.

Comment: The probability that the sum is even is $\frac{6}{9}\times \frac{5}{8}\times \frac{4}{7}+ \frac{3}{9}\times \frac{2}{8}\times \frac{6}{7}+ \frac{3}{9}\times \frac{6}{8}\times \frac{2}{7} + \frac{6}{9} \times \frac{3}{8}\times \frac{2}{7}= \frac{19}{42}$

Comment: @HussienMohamed let us break down what that calculation you just performed was... focusing for the moment at the first part of it in particular... $\frac{6}{9}\times\frac{5}{8}\times\frac{4}{7}$...  It would appear as though the $\frac{6}{9}$ is in reference to having drawn an oddnumbered ball from the bag, there having been six of them out of nine balls total.  Then following that, having drawn another oddnumbered ball, there having been five remaining odd balls out of eight balls total... followed by yet another odd numbered ball... Odd+odd+odd = odd.  You seem to have mixed "even" and "odd"

Comment: @HussienMohamed That is still incorrect. The hypergeometric approach is the correct way to get here.

Comment: @HussienMohamed I will point out that while manually multiplying each individual term out like you have is certainly a correct approach (*once you correct your mistake involving which outcomes correspond to even sums versus odd sums*), it is highly tedious.  If the question were about thousands of marbles, picking hundreds at a time, you most certainly do not want to be using your approach.  You wouldn't be able to fit your answer on a sheet of paper, much less feasibly be able to calculate with it.  Having organized your thoughts with binomial coefficients saves time, space, and energy.